# ActionLink behaving differently

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an action link like:

```
 <%=Html.ActionLink<ArticlesController>(x => x.Modify(item.id),"Modify") %>
```

This is working perfectly rendering the link like:

```
http://localhost:53574/Articles/Modify?idArticle=8
```

The same view is rendered in another page but this time the link is rendered with an empty href:

```
<a href="">Modify</a>
```

Could someone explain me what this is happening?

Comment: Check your action methods are returning the same/correct data.

Answer (score 0):

Does the different view belong to a different controller? What are the properties on the item in that other view/does it have an ID?

Answer (score 0):

The Futures Html.ActionLink method will inspect your route mapping to determine an appropriate "outbound" URL.  Please check your Global.asax.cs file's Application_Start method.  Something about the other controller isn't mapping correctly.

Also, where is item.id coming from?